# How to change select event on legend in echarts?

Tags: echarts

I need behavior like legend item is hovered, when emphasis: {focus: 'series'}.

What we have how:

1. untouched legend

[image: untouched legend]

2. Video Ads field is clicked and data remove from chart(yellow line is disappear):

[image: touched legend]

3. What do I need? So that the yellow line does not disappear, but changes color to a faded one

[image: yellow line is still here]

I will be glad of any tips